# How to: One Up' for points and rounds in a game?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class GameController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @games = Game.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @games }
    end
  end

  def start_game
    session[:round] = 1
    session[:points] = 0
    @round = session[:round]
    @points = session[:points] 
  end

  def next_round
  @round += 1
  @points += 1200
  end

  def game_over
  puts "Game Over."
  end

  def highscore
  puts "Leaderboard action here."
  end

  def generate_round
    numbers = Array.new(6){rand(9)}
     @addition = []
     @display = numbers
    numbers.inject do |s, i|
       @addition << s + i
       @addition.last
    end
  end

  def new
    start_game
  generate_round
  puts @points
  puts @round

  if session[:addition]
     if not session[:addition].index(params[:guess].to_i).nil?
        puts "Correct."
        next_round
     else
        game_over
        puts "Wrong anwser."
        highscore
     end
  end
  session[:addition] = @addition
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
    end
  end   
end
```

Hey guys, So Im trying to build a simple game in rails. 
Its premise is to add all the numbers up in your memory and type in the highest sum you can within a predefined time limit. 
Right now I able to generate the numbers and check for correct answers, however I don`t know how to loop the method in a way that points are added after each successful round.

I`m assuming the problem is that for each instance of "new" it sets the start_game method again, thus zeroing the points and round again?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, every time you hit the 'new' action it will start your game over again.
You could do something like below to get it to keep over multiple requests to 'new'

```
  def start_game
    session[:round] ||= 1
    session[:points] ||= 0
    @round = session[:round]
    @points = session[:points] 
  end

  def game_over
    session[:round] = nil
    session[:points] = nil
    puts "Game Over."
  end
```

Comment: Unfortunetly this still doesn`t allow me to go past round 2. I`ve also tried doing if session[:round] = 0 then start_game else generate_round. But that also yields the same result (stops adding points and rounds after the first increment.