# What's wrong with this loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

```
    class GameController < ApplicationController

      def index
        @games = Game.all
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html 
        end
      end

      def start_game
        session[:round] ||= 1
        session[:points] ||= 0
        @round = session[:round]
        @points = session[:points] 
      end

      def next_round
        session[:round] += 1
        session[:points] += 1200
                    @round = session[:round]
                @points = session[:points]
      end

      def generate_round
        numbers = Array.new(6){rand(9)}
        @addition = []
        @display = numbers
        numbers.inject do |s, i|
            @addition << s + i
            @addition.last
        end
      end

      def new
        if @round == nil
            start_game
            generate_round
        else
            generate_round
        end

        if session[:addition]
            if not session[:addition].index(params[:guess].to_i).nil?
                puts "Correct."
                next_round
            else
                puts 'Game over.'
            end
        end

        session[:addition] = @addition
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html 
        end
      end    

    end
```

Hey guys,
I`m trying to put together this mini game in ruby that depends on guessing numbers.
After every guess points are added and the level is increased by one.

However with the current code, I`m getting stuck at round 2.
Most likely something is resetting those variables for some reason but I can seem to pin point what it is.

Would be grateful for any kind of help.

::Edit::

Code updated. Problem solved!
Thanks for the help @blackbird07, @robertodecurnex and @fl00r!

Comment: Curious, what is "not" in Ruby? I'm not familiar with it...then again I'm a Ruby newb.

Comment: What all this stuff is doing in controller?

Comment: This is pretty much a repost of your question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654978/how-to-one-up-for-points-and-rounds-in-a-game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not increase the counters for session[:round] and session[:points] in your next_round action. Do this and it should work.

```
session[:round] += 1
session[:points] += 1200
@round = session[:round]
@points = session[:points]
```

Comment: I thought that's achieved by doing += 1 and since the session for both are set as instance variables it transfer to the the session also. (It does increase up till round 2 and 1200pts = one iteration) ::edit:: You sir are a true gentleman, problem fixed! Thank You. Still would like to know why the instance variable doesn`t update the assigned sessions also though.

Comment: That's because you have to take robertodecurnex's answer into account as well: if @round == 0 then; plus you have to read session[:round] in your new action -> will update my post above

Comment: The instance variable is not bound to the session value. The session is the only thing that is persisted between requests. This is why you have to initialize the instance variable from the session in every action you are calling

Answer (score 1):

Controller is stateless so of course all variables are reseted each time you call it.

You should use some datastorage (database, filesystem) to store your current state.

And another your problem is that all this code shouldn't belong to controller at all.

Comment: I believe he intends for *session* to hold game state. But, I agree controller is too phat.

Comment: @Meltemi, yep, but it looks like he never updates session data.

Comment: @fl00r - As @meltemi pointed out, I thought that session[] would allow me to store the current state until I destroy it. Is there any way I can fix it at its current state? I would like it just to work (go beyond round 2) for now. Then most likely I`ll rewrite it to a more proper rails app with a DB and stuff defined in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are keeping the round on the session you should use the session value instead of the instance variable or at least create a filter to set this variable on every request.

Using the filter:

```
before_filter :set_round

private

def set_round
  @round = session[:round]
end
```

The new method (action) is making the following:

```
if @round = 0 then
```

It's assigning `0` to `@round` instead of compare it.

Try `if @round == 0` or just `if @round.zero?`

You will need also to increase the session value and not just the `@round` variable one.

Remember:

```
=     #=> Assignation
==    #=> Equality, usually overwritten by the classes to return true base on the equality of the state/attributes of two objects.
===   #=> Equality, usually defined to compare the identity of two objects (to return true only if both objects are actually the same object).
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, however even if I fix it to if @round == nil that still doesn't fix the problem. Round is still stuck at 2 after each successful guess.

Comment: That's because of the session problem. You need to update both the session and the instance variable. Btw, you can just use the session all the time instead of the variable.